# iOS multiple collection view

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview

In iOS (Objective-C) am trying to create a view like shounw below. There will two sections on that view. First one will be for the user profile information and the section part will be there captured snaps. I will show that snaps in a collection view. I need when the user scroll the the collectionview, the screen will go up.

Can any one please suggest me how can I do this?

[image]

Comment: u want horizontal or vertical scrolling and what u want to move first view or second. please edit ur question and give brief details what u want and what u have tried

Comment: I need vertical scrolling

Answer (score 1):

Please download the sample app.
[Click here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B99J5WpIrSZEZmdiQ3h2UjVyRlE)

Steps:

1) Add scrollView and set constraints as the project shared

2) Add another view(named as contentview) on top of scrollview and set constraints.

3) Top of the contentview add another view for your profile and at bottom add uicollectionview.

4) Change uicollection view scrolling to horizontal.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. Suppose there are 100 images in my collectionview, and every row will contain 3-4 images. Now when the user scroll , the collectionview will go to upward. Upper scrollview position will also move according to that.I have edited the image of my requirement. Can you please suggest me how to do that?

Comment: If my answer helped you please accept the answer and give thumbs up. I didn't understand your second choice question. Please can you explain briefly.

Comment: Hi, In your previous answer you have fixed the container and and uicollectionview height. But I need that the uicollectionview height will be flexible. You have done horizontal scrolling in the uicollectionview.But I need vertical scrolling.So that when the content will increase, I can scroll the collectionview. In that case the your upperview will also move upside according with the view. For better understanding can you please check this app in [itunes] (https://itunes.apple.com/app/id835599320) ?

Comment: As far as I saw the musical.ly app, actually its scrolling is not enable. But to show the rows it dynamically increases the height constraint. You can achieve  that by following steps:

Comment: 1) Draw an outlet from UICollectionViewHeightConstraint and name it as "collectionViewHeightConstraint"

2) Now you have to calculate the height for your collection view. For example,  you want to show 3 thumbnails in a row just like musical.ly. So for the 4th row you need to increase the uicollectionview height and that is previous row + height of single row. Same for 9th row, 12th, 15th ... etc.
code for increase UICollectionViewHeight as follows:

 self.collectionViewHeightConstraint.constant =[collectionviewCurrentHeight]+[rowheight];

[self.view layoutIfNeeded];

Comment: Thank you for your answer. can you please give me a demo just like previous one? If possible.

Comment: Hey, I'm sorry for late reply. Here is the link to the demo 
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0B99J5WpIrSZEdzJ3Y1djUnhBbUE

Answer (score 1):

Simply add profile view to header of collection view.